# Php Error on executing file_get_contents($file) in the second iteration

Tags: php

I have a number of jason format .txt files. I am trying to get each file one by one, modify its contents and then put those contents back to the file. For this purpose I have executed a loop that does this process for every file. The loop runs absolutely fine in the first iteration but in the second iteration it throws a warning "Warning: file_get_contents(../videos/list2.txt  ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\wamp\www\dtt_admin_V2\pages\jason2.php on line 85". 
The argument in file_get_contents(../videos/list2.txt) is correct. There is no issue in it. I can't what is causing this error. Any help regarding this error is much apperciated.[snap Shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMoqo.png)[snap shot of my code where the error is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob6V8.png)

Comment: I am running it on wamp.

Comment: Maybe try posting line 85 because even if you think the argument is correct, clearly PHP thinks otherwise

Comment: Are you failing to close the file after an update?

Comment: Please show us the code or we are debugging blind.

Comment: how can I share my code here? 
Sorry I have posted a question almost first time here.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts?

Comment: You can look at my code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zJCwiyHLA6W14GM8JuN3T-LntTVT1w6b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Copy and paste the code in your question and format it as code with one of the formatting buttons. Please don't place all of your code, but only the relevant parts.